# Setting up application wide Key Listeners

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-shortcuts

How do i setup application wide key listeners (keyboard shortcuts), so that when a key combination (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) is pressed, a certain action is invoked in a Java application.

I know keyboard shortcuts can be set `JMenuBar` menu items, but in my case the application does not have a menu bar.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check out the [How To Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) section of the Java tutorial.

You need to create and register an `Action` with your component's `ActionMap` and the register a (`KeyStroke`, *Action Name*) pair in one of your application's component's `InputMap`s.  Given that you don't have a `JMenuBar` you could simply register the key bindings with a top-level `JPanel` in your application.

For example:

```
Action action = new AbstractAction("Do It") { ... };

// This is the component we will register the keyboard shortcut with.
JPanel pnl = new JPanel();

// Create KeyStroke that will be used to invoke the action.
KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_T, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK | InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK);

// Register Action in component's ActionMap.
pnl.getActionMap().put("Do It", action);

// Now register KeyStroke used to fire the action.  I am registering this with the
// InputMap used when the component's parent window has focus.
pnl.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(keyStroke, "Do It");
```