# keyListener on JFrame not reacting

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener

I want when user press `enter` button on keyboard, then program should function like when click on `ok` button.

My code:

```
public class T3 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JButton okBtn;

public T3() {
    this.setFocusable(true);
    this.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // if enter button is pressed in keyboard, then show "Enter Button pressed" message
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            // if enter button is pressed in keyboard, then show "Enter Button pressed" message
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    });
    add(createForm(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(400, 500);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new T3();
        }
    });
}

public JPanel createForm() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    okBtn = new JButton("Ok");
    okBtn.addActionListener(this);
    panel.add(okBtn);
    return panel;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == okBtn) {
        System.out.println("Enter Button pressed");
    }
}
}
```

Now, Not react !

Comment: Take a look to [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java KeyListener for JFrame is being unresponsive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286727/java-keylistener-for-jframe-is-being-unresponsive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KeyListeners don't work on containers when a child component has the focus. You will need an application wide KeyListener. Check out this SO question:

[Setting up application wide Key Listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231622/setting-up-application-wide-key-listeners)